# How to auto dispatch_group_leave

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'am now using dispatch_group to manage multi-threads in my project. something like this:

```
- (void)functionA{
    self.taskGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    // Call functionB more than one time
    [self functionB];
    ...
    [self functionB];

    dispatch_group_notify(..., ^{
        // Do something if all [self functionB] complete
    });

- (void)functionB{
    dispatch_group_enter(self.taskGroup);

    if (condition) {
        dispatch_group_leave(self.taskGroup);
        return;
    }

    [self doSomethingInBackground:^{
        NSLog(@"completed!");
        dispatch_group_leave(self.taskGroup);
    }];
}
```

My question is how to automatically call dispatch_group_leave when functionB is complete, so that I don't need to call it before every return statement in functionB or any background task called by functionB.

Comment: Hello! Why don't you use simply `dispatch_group_async` (`dispatch_group_async_f`) for dispatching work in `functionB` and assocoating it with your group instead of manually  `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave`? (`dispatch_group_async`
Submits a block to a dispatch queue and associates the block with the specified dispatch group.
)

Comment: @mike-dutka thanks for your comment, the reason is that I want to make sure all background task called by functionB are also complete. For example, the **NSLog** in my code.

Comment: How you can determine is function return or start background task and return? I think you can insert this logic in `doSomethingInBackground` method. So before start task enter, finished - leave. And remove `enter` and `leave` from syncronious call. In some cases you can't do this, in some otherwise.

Comment: @ybbaigo, using `dispatch_group_async_f(.......functionB....)` instead `[self functionB];` should do a trick for you. `dispatch_group_async` associates the block with the specified dispatch group so it should be possible to catch the moment when all fucntionB async calls completed by `dispatch_group_notify`.

Comment: @Sk0prion, I don't need to distinguish them. For every function return or background task return, I will leave. that's why I complain here, I have to do it manually, it's very easy to forget to leave if funtionB is complex. I have also tried the way you propose here, it doesn't work, since functionB will leave before background task enter. and the notify function will trigger before the background task in functionB done.

Comment: @ybbaigo `#define m_return dispatch_group_leave(self.taskGroup);return` you can experiment with define

Comment: @Sk0prion, wow~ simple method but work best. Great answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sk0prion mentioned in comments, I can simply involve macro here.

```
#define m_return dispatch_group_leave(self.taskGroup);return
```